# Android file associations not working (intent filter, by extension)

Tags: android, associations, file-extension

I've been trying to associate my app with vrtci file extension, but it's not working. I've been looking across the internet to see  what I've been doing wrong and nothing helped. Here is the section in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainCardActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".CardInstaller" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.vrtci" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- For http -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.vrtci" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.vrtci" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.vrtci" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.vrtci" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.vrtci" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.vrtci" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- For https -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.vrtci" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.vrtci" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.vrtci" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.vrtci" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.vrtci" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.vrtci" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- For file browsers and google drive -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.vrtci" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.vrtci" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.vrtci" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.vrtci" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.vrtci" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.vrtci" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I've just found a solution which did it for me.

Create intent-filter with scheme "content" and do not specify the host element at all.

```
     <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.vrtci" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.vrtci" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.vrtci" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.vrtci" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.vrtci" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: This is wrong. If the "host" element is not specified, it just causes that Android completely ignores the "android:pathPattern" element. The file is opened in the app only because the scheme and mime type match (as stated in the official doc: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element).

E. g. in my device I don't have any other app which supports "*/*" mime type for "content" scheme so the files are directly opened in my app, but the path pattern is ignored and even if I change the file's extension it is still opened in the app.

Comment: @MilošČernilovský Is right, `pathPattern` is ignored without a `android:host` defined. So the above is listening to `android:mimeType="*/*"` which is effectively everything.

Comment: Yes, I've given up on using file associations in Android, because Android is not prepared for them. It only works for mime types, but also not very well due to very different implementations in 3rd party file managers. Instead it is better to allow the user select a file inside the given app via an Intent for a file manager.