# Android Java: File Association and Intent handling

Tags: java, android, fragment, file-association

I am trying to implement an Intent Filter, that associates a particular file extension with my application.
I searched for examples but unfortunately found no solution. All of the information that I found is old (10 years ago) and I suggest it is not applicable anymore.

I have a local file with the file extension ".bib" (BibTeX file type) that is stored in my internal storage. I want to be able to import this file into my application. My import-Methods are in a Fragment named **DefaultOpener**.

I have several issues:

**1. Association with custom file type**

I tried several suggestions, that did not work (including `android:pathPattern`). As in this example [Android file associations not working (intent filter, by extension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26664332/android-file-associations-not-working-intent-filter-by-extension), I declared the Intent Filter in AndroidManifest.xml, but my phone does not recognize the ".bib" file type and tells me that there is no program that can open such a file.

Is there another approach to register my ".bib" file type?

**2. Calling a method from a Fragment, when my app is selected to open a ".bib" file**

I used the following Intent Filter, which works. Unfortunately, it considers all file types (because of the `android:mimeType="*/*"`).

```
    <intent-filter android:name=".DefaultOpener">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data
            android:host="*"
            android:mimeType="*/*"
            android:scheme="content" />
    </intent-filter>
```

As already mentioned, this is not my desired result.
I wish to be able to associate my app only with ".bib" files.
If I open my ".bib" file with my app, then the MainActivity is opened. I wish to call a method from a Fragment, named **DefaultOpener**. How can I do this?

P.S. my target Android version is Android 10.

Comment: Custom file extensions have never been supported well on Android, and modern versions of Android they are just about defunct. You could try a MIME type of `application/x-bibtex`, though I do not know that Android is going to recognize that.

Comment: Thanks for the important information. I tried your suggestion, but Android did not recognize it.